# Custom Repository Implementation is not being recognized

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am currently working on a project where I have created the following custom Repository:

```java
public interface ServiceRepository<T extends ServiceEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, UUID>, ServiceRepositoryCustom {
}

public interface ServiceRepositoryCustom {
    List<ServiceEntity> findAllContainingName(String query);
}

@Repository("Repo")
public class ServiceRepositoryCustomImpl implements ServiceRepositoryCustom {


    private final EntityManager em;

    public ServiceRepositoryCustomImpl(EntityManager em) {
        System.out.println("I got constructed");
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ServiceEntity> findAllContainingName(String name) {
        System.out.println("I got called with: " + name);
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<ServiceEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(ServiceEntity.class);

        Root<ServiceEntity> serviceEntity = cq.from(ServiceEntity.class);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        if(name != null)  {
            // predicates.add(cb.equal(serviceEntity.get("name"), name));
            predicates.add(cb.like(serviceEntity.get("name"), name + "%"));
        }
        cq.where(predicates.toArray(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));

        return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }
}
```

The print statement "I got called with: " never gets called. So for whatever reason Spring Boot is not running the method through my custom implementation.

Any suggestions? Any help is much appreciated

Edit:
Here is the code that injects and uses the Repository in question

```java
@Repository
public interface PineappleServiceRepository extends ServiceRepository<PineappleServiceEntity> {
}

@Component("Registry")
@DependsOn({"Context", "Repo"})
public class Registry {
    private final List<ServiceRepository<? extends ServiceEntity>> serviceRepositories = new ArrayList<>();

    public Registry(PineappleServiceRepository pineappleServiceRepository) {
        this.serviceRepositories.add(pineappleServiceRepository);
    }
}
```

Edit 2:
The code prints "I got constructed"

Edit 3:
Class where `findAllContainingName` is called

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@DependsOn("Registry")
public class ServiceController {

    private final Registry registry;

    public ServiceController(@NotNull Registry registry) {
        this.registry = registry;
    }

    @GetMapping("")
    List<ServiceEntity> all(@RequestParam("q") String query) {
        return getAllServices(query);
    }

    private @NotNull List<ServiceEntity> getAllServices(String query) {
        List<ServiceEntity> response = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ServiceRepository<? extends ServiceEntity> repo: this.registry.getServiceRepositories()){
             response.addAll(repo.findAllContainingName(query));
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Edit 4:

Here the entities:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "services")
public abstract class ServiceEntity {

    protected @Id
    UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
    protected String name;

    // Constructor + Getters and Setters
}

@Entity
public class PineappleServiceEntity extends ServiceEntity {
    // Additional Properties, matching Constructors, Getters and Setters
}
```

Comment: Can you upload the code where you are injecting and using the repo?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly I added the information you requested

Comment: Does it print "I got constructed"? Are you missing something fundamental?

Comment: It prints "I got constructed"

Comment: I still can't see where you are calling `findAllContainingName`. Can you update the code?

Comment: You should also add entity classes. Or minimum reproducible example would be even better

Comment: What happens if instead of injecting `Registry` you inject  `PineappleServiceRepository` into the controller and call `findAllContainingName` directly on it?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly the error persists

Comment: @ShivajiPote I added the entity classes

Comment: I was trying to reproduce your issue with above classes but I am getting error `No property 'findAllContainingName' found for type 'PineappleServiceEntity'`.  So I wanted to check PineappleServiceEntity properties. Can you add them?

Comment: @ShivajiPote This is the same error I am getting, which I thought was a result of Spring Boot not recognizing my custom interface/ class and instead referring to the Spring Boot construct based of off function name, that is why I ignored it. I checked, the `PineappleServiceEntity` has no further properties. It is however intended that other inheritors or `ServiceEntity` would have such functionality. Thank you for looking it this

Comment: Note: I confirmed that Spring auto function generation is the origin of the property not found error, by changing the function name to findAllByName which then allowed Spring to run, however it still didn’t call my method, it merely used the auto generated one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to reproduce your problem and fix it. Issue with your code is that your `PineappleServiceRepository` is not extending `ServiceRepositoryCustom` directly. It seems your repository needs to implement it directly if you are accessing custom repository methods from that repository. I got that idea from [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/custom-spring-data-repository/) post.

So to fix your issue, either remove `PineappleServiceRepository`(as you don't have any properties in PineappleEntity) and use `ServiceRepository` to call that custom method or make `PineappleServiceRepository` extend `ServiceRepositoryCustom`.

I have pushed changes to [GitHub](https://github.com/spote87/stackoverflow/tree/main/jpa/q72930189) with fix. You can take a look. If you want to keep `PineappleServiceRepository` and access custom method using this repository, let me know, I can update code.

Comment: I solved it my making `PineappleServiceRepository` ALSO extend `ServiceRepositoryCustom`. Thank you so much